# C# make class from swagger.json as part of build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nswag

In ViaulStudio I clicked some buttons via *Add Connected Service* and have ended up with a C# class that I can use to call a HTTP API.

It looks like the HTTP API produces a json metadata document that describes the HTTP API, and then this is used to generate the C# class.

In order to fix the build I copied the generated `.cs` file out of the `obj` directory and added it to the soure control -- I presume this is wrong?

It seems that it should be possible to add the `.json` file to the repository instead and have the C# class generated as a pre-build event.

Is this the right idea? How are you supposed to get this to work with source control?

Comment: Did you follow one of the guides from https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag#readme and which project type you are using. For example for web api project you just need to register config in owin middle ware and it gives you UI and everything on /swagger

Comment: The webAPI project is showing Swagger and making the json. This is to be consumed from a `net5.0` DLL. Do I generate the code from the json then add the code to the DLL repository? Or do I add the json to the repository and have the code generated by the build?

Comment: Have the code generated by the build is better. so you have it all up to date and not forget to rebuild if json changes

Comment: Tha'ts what I thought -- better to have the code generated by the build. However, this appears to be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- NSwagSharp is buggy!
        GenerateExceptionClasses forces it off but not on.
        Therefore we have to generate ApiException, move it to a separate file, and then reference it.
        -->
        <OpenApiReference Include="some_api.json" Namespace="CompanyName.SomeProduct.SomeApiProxy" ClassName="SomeApiProxy" OutputPath="$(ProjectDir)SomeApiProxy.cs">
            <CodeGenerator>NSwagCSharp</CodeGenerator>
            <Options>/AdditionalNamespaceUsages:CompanyName.SomeProduct.Exceptions /GenerateExceptionClasses:false</Options>    
        </OpenApiReference>

    </ItemGroup>
```